# can you do buy 1 get 1 50% off on 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

I have been trying to create a promo through my Magento store of buy 1 get 1 50% off my cheapest item but only want it on footwear and i cant seem to work it out. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this module may be it is helpful

```
Download the latest version of this free magento extension / module via Github here  https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-buy-x-get-y-free
```

Comment: Yes, this will work..I have used earlier